# How can i find what bindings supports multi-platform?

Tags: .net, wcf

In WCF, what are the **bindings** which support multi-platform systems communication ?

I need to know which bindings support .NET and Unix and Mac and Java.

Does the fact that I'm  using WCF mandate that the other side be .NET?

Comment: No, you can't see who downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basicHttpBinding` and `wsHttpBinding` and the related bindings all are based entirely on industry standards so should interoperate.

Any of the `net*` bindings are obviously not interoperable.

You do not need both sides to be .NET.

Comment: " the related bindings " ?? which ?  Is it mandatory that one of them must me .net ? (cause WCF is in .net...?)

Comment: `WS2007HttpBinding` and `WSFederationHttpBinding` and `WS2007FederationHttpBinding`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx.

Comment: thanks. one last question to understand : does at least 1 of the sides has to be in .net ?

Comment: This is for homework, right? Of course one side has to be .NET if one side is WCF because WCF is part of .NET. The other side can be anything.

Comment: no my friend  , this is for pure understanding. thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of is just because a binding is *designed* to be interoperable doesn't mean it will necessarily work with other platform's toolkits.

For example: wsHttpBinding supports WS-AtomicTransaction which is an agreed standard. However, most other web service toolkits do not support WS-AtomicTransaction

Or even more extreme: Android and iOS don't support SOAP so you would have to use webHttpBinding

For maximum reach with SOAP you will probably only be able to use basicHttpBinding. To use richer protocols requires that the other platform supports those protocols. And, especially if you don't know who your service consumers will be, forcing use of WS-Security, etc will only preclude people from using your service

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the HTTP endpoints are the ones that are compatible with other services out of the box. I have an [example wcf service](https://github.com/justaprogrammer/EchoService/) that binds to several endpoint that I use for examples and such and I'll touch on the three http endpoints setup in the [web.config](https://github.com/justaprogrammer/EchoService/blob/master/EchoService.Website/Web.config):

- **[webHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176.aspx)** This one is setup as a JSON service, but I believe that you can also configure it for other simple non-SOAP http requests. This endpoint is meant for commmunicating via standard http calls as opposed to SOAP.
- **[basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx)** This is a very basic SOAP implementation that does not implement any of the WS-* extensions This means it is the most interoperable with non-Microsoft SOAP clients.
- **[wsHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299.aspx)** This implements several of the WS-* extensions than basicHttpBinding. If your soap client supports these, this is a good idea to use. For example, [WSO's WSF framework for php](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/) will allow you to consume web services with this binding
- Finally, not an endpoint, but an extension Eyal P's **[WCFExtras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com)** will amongst other things flatten WCF WSDLs into one file. If you look at a WCF WSDL in a web browser it referces another WSDL and four XSD documents.